# jQuery target two wildcard classes

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use/target two wildcard classes with jQuery? In the same variable, so I don't have to create two variables and therefore two functions doing the same thing.

I suspected it may be the following but this has not worked:

```
var triggers = $('[class^="polaroid-carousel__"].trigger', '[class^="polaroid-carousel__"].trigger');
```

Current code:

```
var triggers = $('[class^="polaroid-carousel__"].trigger');
var triggers2 = $('[class^="social-wall__"].trigger');

$(triggers).each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $('#modal-holder').modal('show');
    var triggerTarget = $(this).data('target');
    $(triggerTarget).show();
    $('#modal-holder').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(triggerTarget).modal('hide');
    });
  })
});

$(triggers2).each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $('#modal-holder').modal('show');
    var triggerTarget = $(this).data('target');
    $(triggerTarget).show();
    $('#modal-holder').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(triggerTarget).modal('hide');
    });
  })
});
```

Edit:

With the answers provided so far of which work, I just realised that it's now triggering both when one is clicked. It needs to trigger one or the other not both at the same time, just realised this is a mistake on setup I think.

Comment: $(childSelector, parentSelector) is what you are doing.  Put them both in a single string, with the comma in the string.

Comment: var triggers = $('[class^="polaroid-carousel__"]', '[class^="polaroid-carousel__"]').trigger;

Comment: Hmm I just realised that it's now triggering both when one is clicked. It needs to trigger one or the other not both at the same time, just realised this is a mistake on setup I think.

Comment: Any time you click one of those triggers it is going to create a new 'hidden.bs.modal' on the modal-holder, so you will be creating multiple bindings on that guy, which is an issue with your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the selectors into a single selector...

```js
var $triggers = $('[class^="polaroid-carousel__"].trigger, [class^="social-wall__"].trigger');

$triggers.on('click', function() {
    $('#modal-holder').modal('show');
    var triggerTarget = $(this).data('target');
    $(triggerTarget).show();
    $('#modal-holder').one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(triggerTarget).modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm I just realised that it's now triggering both when one is clicked. It needs to trigger one or the other not both at the same time, just realised this is a mistake on setup I think.

Comment: I just changed the inner binding from 'on' to 'one' so it will only execute once, since logically i would assume the modal can only be open for one target at a time.  Try that and see if anything changes.

Comment: Also verify that they both don't have the same `data-target` in their markup.

Comment: Absolutely spot on mate, working perfect now. Could you explain the use of the $ in the variable, want to know what that is that doing to learn from.

Comment: They all have a unique data-target, got that sorted already, thanks for the note though.

Comment: It's just a naming convention.  Naming a variable '$something' usually indicates that the value of it should/will be a jQuery element.  So going forward if you know that, you don't have to guess if you need to stick it in a $() to have access to the jQuery methods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @taplar